# How can i match string between GROUP BY and first space without comma before it?

Tags: regex

There are strings:

```
GROUP BY id,asd, asddd, adfasd LIMIT 4;
=> id,asd, asddd, adfasd

GROUP BY id,asd, asddd, adfasd order id asc;
=> id,asd, asddd, adfasd

GROUP BY id limit 4;
=> id
```

How can I match values between **GROUP BY** and first space without comma...?

Comment: What language/tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
GROUP BY (.*[^\s]+\s*,\s*[^\s]+)
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: It works! I just replaced single spaces with **\s**! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't work if there is a space before the comma, like: `GROUP BY id , asd limit 4;`

Comment: @Toto I updated my regex, which now passed all your test cases.  At some point I would just stop here.  If a regex lets the OP handle all his data, then maybe it is good enough for an answer.

Comment: OK, it works. Just for info: `[^\s]` can be written `\S`

Answer (score 1):

This regex does the job: `(?<=GROUP BY\s+)(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)`

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=GROUP BY\s+): lookbehind, make sure we have "GROUP BY"
(               : start group 1    
  \w+           : 1 or more word character
  (?:           : start non capture group
    \s*         : 0 or more spaces
    ,           : a comma
    \s*         : 0 or more spaces
    \w+         : 1 or more word character
  )*            : group may occurs 0 or more times
)               : end group 1
```

Input strings:

```
GROUP BY id,asd, asddd, adfasd LIMIT 4;
GROUP BY id,asd, asddd, adfasd order id asc;
GROUP BY id , asd limit 4;
```

Output:

```
'id,asd, asddd, adfasd'
'id,asd, asddd, adfasd'
'id , asd'
```